# Reset all SQL Server database values c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have a SQL Server table with two columns.

Want to reset all value with new ones

I did tried using update command but I got can not convert string to int error.

I want to update all of the columns

How am I will make this happen?

Comment: Show your code (especially the update command) because you are clearly trying to use a string as int

Comment: what sql did you use?

Comment: Edit your post and put a example of the code you tried and failed, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can't you just `cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set all the entries to 0 you can simply remove the `WHERE` clause then set Number equal to 0.

```
UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = 0
```

If you want to use a parameter (though there is not much point if it is hardcoded), you can do this..

```
UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = @nm
```

Though I think the exception you are receiving is occurring when setting the parameter. Try setting `@nm` as an int, not a string... (notice lack of quotes around 0)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
```

All together without parameter...

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
    (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
    C:\WpfApplication\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = 0";
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or with parameter..

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
    (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
    C:\WpfApplication\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = @nm";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This code won't work since it doesn't filter on the names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the values to `0`, you have to set the value to `0`:

```
UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = @nm WHERE [Name] = @Name
```

In your code, `@nm`, contains 0, so the above query should work.

I think the actual problem is that you are trying to match all lines by a single comparison. That isn't going to work. You have to make an `in` from the select, like so:

```
UPDATE [People] SET [Number] = @nm WHERE [Name] in (@Name1, @Name2, @Name3)
```

And pass in the names as separate parameters.